# How to rewrite CASE expression to short-circuit evaluation

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

I would like to know if there is any way to rewrite the EXPRESSION in the query (just expression, not the whole query) to short-circuit useless evaluation of THEN phase?

Demo data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Docs (
    ID INT NOT NULL
    ,DocType TINYINT NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE #DocsItems (
    IDDocs INT NOT NULL
    ,Amount NUMERIC(19,6)
    );

INSERT INTO #Docs(ID, DocType) VALUES(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2),(6,2);
INSERT INTO #DocsItems(IDDocs,Amount) VALUES(3,50.),(3,25.),(3,33.),(4,44.),(4,123.),(6,11.);
```

Subject query:

```
SELECT
    -- expression
    SumAmount = CASE 
                    WHEN D.DocType <> 1 THEN (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM #DocsItems WHERE IDDocs = D.ID)
                END
FROM #Docs D
WHERE D.DocType = 1  -- so CASE condition evaluates to False
```

Query plan:
[image]

If I rewrite the query (on purpose) to:

```
SELECT
    -- expression
    SumAmount = CASE 
                    WHEN 2 = 1 /* rewrite*/  THEN (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM #DocsItems WHERE IDDocs = D.ID)
                END
FROM #Docs D
WHERE D.DocType = 1
```

The plan goes the way it should / could / would  in the original query:
[image]

Comment: It's doing useless nested loop with #DocsItems table table scan. I know that in MS SQL Server CASE not always short-circuits - this is the example. I want to know if there is a way to rewrite this expression to short-circuit evaluation of this - always false - condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What is currently happening**

When running your query, the table scan, stream agg & compute scalar operators are not evaluated at runtime.

[image]

[image]

---

**Why is it happening**

The apply NL join means that for each row in `#Docs`, return a row from `#Docsitems` that matches the predicate. This predicate should be `WHERE IDDocs = D.ID`

But the compute scalar operator (`EXPR1007`) next to the select (the actual case statement) is calling the scalar function in the inner side of the NL apply (`EXPR1005`) only when `Doctype <> 1`. This as you know cannot happen, and they both return `NULL`.

Compute scalar between NL & SELECT:

[image]

Compute scalar on the inner side of the join:

[image]

This all seems to be due to how the CASE statement functions & removing literals. (difference between `CASE  2 = 1` vs. `CASE WHEN D.DocType <> 1`)

---

**Resolving**

If you change the query to this:

```
SELECT
    -- expression
    SumAmount = 
                     (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM #DocsItems WHERE IDDocs = D.ID AND D.DocType <> 1 )

FROM #Docs D
WHERE D.DocType = 1  -- so CASE condition evaluates to False
```

You should get the execution plan you desire:

[image]

---

**Removing the SELonLOJ rule that is changing the plan on the rewrite.**

*Guessing*

Reverting the rule that was applied to get closer to the CASE WHEN query can be done by adding the hint: `OPTION( QUERYRULEOFF SELonLOJ   )`

```
SELECT
    -- expression
    SumAmount = 
                     (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM #DocsItems WHERE IDDocs = D.ID AND D.DocType <> 1 )

FROM #Docs D
WHERE D.DocType = 1  -- so CASE condition evaluates to False
OPTION( QUERYRULEOFF SELonLOJ   );
```

[image]

Showing the same situation (minus filter & left join) as the case statement, but the runtime elimination is not occuring.

[image]

&

[image]

---

Another rule that seems to get closer to the `case when` when turning it off is `JoinPredNorm`

```
SELECT
    -- expression
    SumAmount = 
                     (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM #DocsItems WHERE IDDocs = D.ID AND D.DocType <> 1 )

FROM #Docs D
WHERE D.DocType = 1  -- so CASE condition evaluates to False
OPTION( QUERYRULEOFF JoinPredNorm   )
```

With the filtering happening on the #Docs table as expected.

[image]

Comment: @jerik1 I'll delete the answer for now since the question has shifted to how to  remove it entirely.